# Profiling en azure webapp?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mongodb, azure

Hemos desarrollado una plataforma WebApi la cual está hospedada en Azure, y utilizando MongoDB como base de datos.

Antes del release, hicimos varias pruebas de carga y soporta hasta 11000 requests por segundo, y ahora mismo tenemos una carga media de alrededor de 200 peticiones por segundo, y todo va suave.

El problema es que, **aleatoriamente** y sin ningún patrón aparente, aparecen picos en la cola de requests HTTP y de conexiones a MongoDB, lo cual genera timeouts en el cliente.

Después de intercambiar varios emails con el departamento de soporte de Azure y comprobar los logs tanto de MongoDB y de Azure, no tenemos la más remota idea de qué puede estar pasando.

Mis preguntas son:

**Alguien ha experimentado el mismo problema?** veo casos parecidos pero no son exactamente lo mismo.

**Alguna herramienta-libreria-framework o algo para poder monitorizar cada peticion, el tiempo que toma cada funcion, y cazar lo que está provocando estos picos?**

Un saludo

Comment: cuando dices cola http quiere decir que usas ServiceBus o similar para enviar las acciones que luego consumen MongoDb?

Comment: No Leandro, es uno de los paneles que muestra Azure con las peticiones http, y cuando no puede servirlas por alguna razon las empieza a encolar y te las muestra en un gráfico

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no se especifica el lenguaje en que está escrita la Web App, las opciones que más pueden llegar a ayudarte son:

1. [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/): Tiene una bonificación si das de alta el servicio desde Azure y tiene un nivel de servicios gratuito que retiene la información durante 7 días.
2. [Azure App Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/application-insights/): También tiene un nivel de servicio gratuito y tiene como pro que lo puedes ver y gestionar directamente desde Azure.

Ambos te van a permitir identificar acciones o procesos internos que pueden estar generando timeouts o deadlocks de recursos.

Pero si hay algún agente externo que están literalmente inundando tu Web App de request de forma maliciosa, va a ser difícil de detectar.

Alternativamente puedes intentar definir un **Escalado automático** de tu App Service en base al tamaño de la [Cola de Peticiones HTTP](http://www.ealsur.com.ar/wp/index.php/2015/09/24/http-queue-length-azure-web-apps/) (HTTP Request Queue Length). De esta manera podrías reaccionar incrementando instancias para absorber mejor el incremento de tráfico y reducir instancias cuando disminuya.

Comment: Hola Matias, gracias por tu mensaje.

La aplicación está desarrollada en C#.

Comment: Actualmente estoy investigando el tema de App Insights, aunque no termino de ver claro cómo sacarle provecho, ya que recibo miles de notificaciones por hora, y quisiera saber si lo que provoca dichos picos es algún usuario en concreto, con algún valor determinado o algo así en la base de datos, pero de momento lo veo quizás demasiado "genérico"

Comment: En ambos casos es difícil aislar el particular, son herramientas que pueden ayudarte a encontrar cuellos de botella en líneas generales, aunque si vas a usar App Insights, como guarda registros de cada Request, podrías utilizar [Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics-tour/) para aislar requests y ver los tiempos de cada uno.